# How to create a URL link on the Unity desktop

Tags: 11.10, unity, url

how do I create a URL link on the desktop? On Lucid one could create a URL by right clicking the desktop anywhere and a menu would appear that allowed the creation of a launchpad location (a URL) and once created when clicked it would launch the desired web location.  How is this accomplished in Oneiric Ocelot?

Comment: My question is "why does Ubuntu not allow me to drag a URL on the the desktop with my mouse like Windows will allow me to do?".

Answer (score 4):

The old GUI dialog is still available if you still want to use this:

Using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will launch the old GUI Dialog and you can create a shortcut on your Desktop:

[image]

**Prerequisites**

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` is installed automatically if you have installed gnome-shell/gnome-fallback.  It is also installed automatically if you have previously installed `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Alternatively, you can install the old gnome-panel without much of the bulk:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop/66918#66918)

Answer (score 1):

As I won't remember the command the next time, weeks ahead, I created an icon in the desktop for creating launchers ("direct access" in Windows parlance).
Somehow it replaces the missing contextual menu option.

The file name is ~/Desktop/makeLauncher.desktop`
The file content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=make launcher
Exec=/home/<your user>/bin/createLauncher  <== replace here
Comment[en_US]=GUI for creating launchers
Name=make launcher
Comment=GUI for creating launchers
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

The executable is another small file named: `/home/<your user>/bin/createLauncher`

```
#! /bin/sh

gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Don't forget to chmod this last file to make it executable.
This displays an icon with a foot-print. Double-clicking it opens the launcher creation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the URL in Firefox and then drag and drop the handle at the left side of the location bar to the desktop. Here's a video (attention: loud music): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6RHvH4R2fM

To drag and drop, you move the mouse pointer to the handle (at the left side of the location bar, as seen in the video), then click and hold the first mouse button (the one where your index finger is) and move the mouse pointer to your desktop while still holding the same mouse button. Once the pointer has reached a place on your desktop where neither Firefox nor any other program is visible, you can release the mouse button, i.e. lift your index finger a bit. During that whole operation, do not press any key on your keyboard.

It works in Oneiric with Unity-2D, Natty with Unity-3D, and probably everywhere else, too.

Comment: I disagree. Dragging from Firefox to desktop does not work in Ubuntu 13.04 .   If I am incorrect, then to do it is a non-standard method (on the mouse) that I have not yet discovered, despite the video link you provide.

Comment: I'm still running Ubuntu 12.04, but I tried it in a VM running 13.04 with Unity, and it still works the same.

Comment: Neither you nor the video reveals what key/mouse combination will do that.

Comment: I edited the answer and tried to explain the concept of drag and drop, although I have the suspicion you already knew that. If it still doesn't work for you, maybe you want to report a bug - look [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

i tried the assorted drag and drop suggestions.  it seemed to work on some web sites but i discovered that i didn't have a link, i had a copy of the web page.  on other sites i would have an icon but it wouldn't work until i had gone thru two dropdowns and selected firefox from a list.
  the gnome create trick above works with some modification.  you don't change the type to location, leave it as application.  it will have a command box where you type        "firefox web site name" (substitute the url of the web page you want complete with the http and : and //). 
for info i'm running 12.04 ( i don't remember the cutsey name).

emmett